# Problem getting the right return value when validating an user using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I would like to get the proper value for `okLogin` when the user is incorrect, and stop the form from going forward, but I've noticed that when I call the function the return is executed first than the ajax call, which should be backwards.

I want the ajax function to update my okLogin variable to false anytime a mismatch happens.

```
<form action="test.html" onsubmit="return loginProcess();">
    <label for="usernameLogin" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Username</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="usernameLogin" required>
    <label for="passwordLogin" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" id="passwordLogin" required>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="loginSubmitBtn" value="Login">
</form>

<script>

function loginProcess() {
    let users, usernameLogin, passwordLogin;
    let ajaxCall = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let okLogin = true;

    usernameLogin = document.getElementById("usernameLogin").value;
    passwordLogin = document.getElementById("passwordLogin").value;

    ajaxCall.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (ajaxCall.readyState == 4 && ajaxCall.status == 200) {

            users = JSON.parse(ajaxCall.responseText);

            for (let item in users) {

                if (item === "username") {
                    if (usernameLogin !== users["username"]) {
                        okLogin = false;
                    }
                    console.log("Username: " + okLogin);
                }

                if (item === "password") {
                    if (passwordLogin !== users["password"]) {
                        okLogin = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ajaxCall.open("GET", "docs/users.json", true);
    ajaxCall.send();
    return okLogin;
}

</script>
```

Comment: The issue is you are calling the `XMLHttpRequest` asynchronously, which in your case should be done *synchronously instead* because your `onsubmit` handler will need something to return (true or false) at that moment in time. Try changing this line `ajaxCall.open("GET", "docs/users.json", true);` to `ajaxCall.open("GET", "docs/users.json", false);` and see what happens.

Comment: @GetSet This should never be recommended as it is a bad practice. JavaScript is perfectly capable of handling async code with either callbacks, promises and async/await.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I more so posted my comment because it uses the OP's code base closely, and thus some learning could take place in that approach, while clarifying where the error is. I personally would go a different route altogether by hiding the real submit button from display, then having an intermediate submit button (of `type="button"`) that handles whatever pre-checks before submitting the form directly or via the hidden button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, your code will always return true; the value of `okLogin`, which you define to be true, will never be anything but that.  This is because `ajaxCall.send()` is asynchronous: it kicks off the AJAX call, but that's all; it doesn't wait for the call to succeed (or fail). So the next thing that happens, every time you call `ajaxCall.send()`, is that you return the current value of `okLogin`, which will be true every single time, because any code which might change its value won't have been executed yet.  (It will only be executed after there is a response to your AJAX request.)  Hope that makes sense; this is a common error when dealing with methods like `send()` which are *asynchronous* - that *start* something (in this case an AJAX request) but don't wait for it to finish before returning. (And in your case, returning a value which will be true every time, because every time, the code in your `ajaxCall.onreadystatechange` function will be executed *after* you return `okLogin`.)

One solution would be to make the AJAX call synchronous, by passing `false` instead of `true` as the last argument to `open()`.  This will work, but it's a seriously bad idea; doing synchronous AJAX is deeply frowned upon, because it causes the user's browser to hang until a response is received.  That could take a few milliseconds (not a problem) but if the response is slow in arriving, it could take a second (very bad), or several seconds (totally unacceptable).

I'd suggest this approach: change this...

```
<form action="test.html" onsubmit="return loginProcess();">
```

...to this:

```
<form class="main-form" action="test.html" onsubmit="loginProcess(); return false;">
```

In other words, when the user submits the form, call `loginProcess()`, which kicks off your AJAX call, then return false (which will, for now, keep the form from being submitted).  We will now also ignore the return value of `loginProcess()`; it's not relevant. I've also added a `class` to your form, which we'll use in a minute.

Now, our strategy will be to have your callback (your `ajaxCall.onreadystatechange` code), which will be executed after a successful response, submit your form, only if `okLogin` is true.  To do that, change your code as follows:

```
    ajaxCall.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (ajaxCall.readyState == 4 && ajaxCall.status == 200) {

            users = JSON.parse(ajaxCall.responseText);

            for (let item in users) {

                if (item === "username") {
                    if (usernameLogin !== users["username"]) {
                        okLogin = false;
                    }
                    console.log("Username: " + okLogin);
                }

                if (item === "password") {
                    if (passwordLogin !== users["password"]) {
                        okLogin = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            // ***** Add the following three lines:
            if (okLogin) {
                document.querySelector('form.main-form').submit()
            }
        }
    }
```

You could also use Promises (`then()`, etc.) but it's probably a good idea to understand callbacks before you tackle promises, if you're trying to understand asynchronous concepts.

Final note: you could also use `async/await` but before doing that, you'd want to understand Promises (and before that callbacks) - but more important, `async/await` may not be available in all of your target browsers; not IE, but also not earlier Edge versions.

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for this!!
So the function will always return false, the only way it can submit something is doing it manually from inside the function with submit function.
Because it works asynchronously, so it doesn't wait for the function to continue, alright I got.

I have some questions though:
- About the security here, what should I do to make this secure? this is only a mini-backend test with json, I have no idea where to start.
- About "fetch" and "async / await", are they the same? which one should I use? Which one is the best for this kind of work?

Comment: @jfelya This - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API discusses differences between Fetch and XMLHttpRequest (you're using the latter, of course). Fetch is newer and more powerful but doesn't work on some older browsers. As for async/await: that's not an alternative to either - it's a newish language feature which can make asynchronous code easier to work with (just as Promises can). I suggest learning about callbacks first, then Promises, then async/await (closely related to Promises). Also, generator functions. But i'd tackle callbacks first.

Comment: @jfelya As for security: you should always use POST instead of GET when sending sensitive information. POST is the default for XmlHttpRequest, but GET is the default for submitting a form. So you should add `method="post"` to your `<form>` tag; username/password then won't be visible in your request URL (much, much more secure). Of course, you should also only send sensitive information over HTTPS, not HTTP. If your site is not HTTPS right now, making it so would be a server-config issue; your code would likely stay the same.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried reading the link before for quite a while, but it was so frustrating that I couldn't understand a thing of that article, I got nothing from it, sorry, maybe it is my fault.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because ajax requests are asynchronous. In other words, the code within `onreadystatechange` is only being defined to be executed later, once the ajax call has returned. That is why your method is returning before the ajax call completes.

I would also note that authentication is an important thing to get right, and I think you would do well to look at some examples of proper authentication. From the looks of it, you are returning a list of all usernames and passwords in plaintext in the call. That's a very insecure design. If you have any intentions of using this for anything other than an experiment, you should not do things this way. In fact, even if you are only using this as an experiment, I would suggest trying to do it a different way just to get the experience of doing things how they ought to be done.

At any rate, the way to make this work as it stands would be, instead of returning, take some action within the callback. It's not clear in the code you submitted exactly what will happen when the `loginProcess` method returns (from the looks of it, nothing happens). You could, perhaps, call some other method with your `onreadystatechange` function with a true or false, and let that function handle whatever ought to happen based on a successful or unsuccessful login.

Example:

```
ajaxCall.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (ajaxCall.readyState == 4 && ajaxCall.status == 200) {
    [your code to check the login here]
    someOtherFunction(okLogin)
  }
}
```

Also, I would suggest you take a look at a more modern way of doing ajax requests, [such as using `fetch` and promises.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Thanks so much for the recommendation.
I've done some fetch examples this month, but I can't understand how it works, I did a lots of examples, but it just looks weird and complicated, is it a best way to do this? I'm not a professional programmer, so I don't have experience in security of logins and modern ways of recovering data.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Your problem is due to the nature of asynchronous JavaScript. Your XMLHTTPRequest takes some time to get a response. Because of that you need to wait before returning a value until the request has been finished. Right now you instantly return `okLogin` without the request having a chance to change it.

So you need to delay that. You can use `async` / `await` to wait for the request to finish and continue with your process. This is all based on [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), an object that can chain callbacks together with the `then` method.

Instead of the `XMLHTTPRequest` constructor, try the [`Fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). It's a more modern version of the same principle, but with a simpler, more powerful workflow and it works with promises.

Now with async / await you can make your function asynchronous, meaning it will take some time to complete, but do something else when it is done. The `await` keyword can be put in front of any promise returning function, like fetch, to *await* the function to complete and get the value from it.

In your code it would look like this.

```
async function loginProcess() {
    let usernameLogin, passwordLogin, response, users;
    let okLogin = true;

    usernameLogin = document.getElementById("usernameLogin").value;
    passwordLogin = document.getElementById("passwordLogin").value;

    response = await fetch("docs/users.json");
    users = await response.json();

    for (let item in users) {
      if (item === "username" && usernameLogin !== item) {
        okLogin = false;
      } else if (item === "password" && passwordLogin !== item) {
        okLogin = false;
      }
    }

    return okLogin;
}
```

```
loginProcess().then((loginStatus) => {
  console.log(loginStatus)
});
```

The function fetches your data with `fetch`, waits for it to finish, then turn the result from JSON into workable value and continues from there.
And because the `loginProcess` itself is asynchronous, it returns a Promise. Read up on those how you can use them. They are a very powerful feature of JavaScript.

Also pay attention to @bodacious. He is making some very good points regarding the security concerns in your code. Do your validation server side, where the code is invisible to the user.

Comment: You said I can try using fetch or async / await, but which of the two should I use? Do they have a difference? Because you used async / await here, even though you said fetch was the best one to go with.
So I would like to know more about that, and thanks so much!

And were do I write the second code? the one with the "then" and the console?

Comment: Use both. Fetch is a substitute for XMLHTTPRequest and will return a promise when called. With async / await you can wait for fetch to `resolve` (finish) and store the value it returns. Without async / await you would have to rely on the `then` method, which is kind of the same thing but works differently. The second part with the `then` and `console` should be in your submit handler.

Comment: Ah okey, what do you mean by "submit handler"?